# How can I render a webform submission on a different page after loading it using a submission id?

Tags: 8, webforms

I'm trying to render the content of the webform submission programmatically onto a different page. I can load the webform submission using the sid, but is it possible to embed the submission in another page similar to the way a webform can be embedded? I can iterate through the submission data and print it out manually, but I want to avoid it since my webform uses various conditionals.

I've tried embedding it similar how a webform object is embedded, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Any hints or pointers for this are really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You mean like rendering the values? Like when you visit a submission as admin where all submission values are printed below each other? I mean you could like the the submission result template does in the Webform module. Or do you mean rendering the form?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do, is use [Webform Content Creator](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_content_creator) to create the content after the submission. And then use entity reference to embed the submission content into your desired page.